# Common type but different methods

Tags: c#, oop, interface, abstract-class

I have three different systems that i have to communicate with. With each system i have to communicate in a different way and obtain different type of data. For example with two systems i have to communicate using a REST API and with the third i have to communicate using a NET.TCP protocol.

My question is, is there a pattern or some kind of abstractions that i could use ?
From what i know it is not possible to have a common type (interface) but different methods without making casts. I am using C#

Comment: Proxy or Adapter pattern would probably do.

Comment: You can abstract away with an interface absolutely anything. Not sure what you mean by "it's not possible"

Comment: It depends on how you want to get the data from those systems. You will one of the systems at  time to get the data or you will get data from all three systems at the same time?

Comment: You can create one interface and three concrete classes .. One for each system and use strategy pattern to decide at runtime from where to get the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use generics

```
public interface IDataSource<TData>
{
    IEnumerable<TData> GetData();
}
```

If you can pass the same kind of parameters describing the source address, e.g. a simple string, you can declare the interface with

```
public interface IDataSource<TData>
{
    IEnumerable<TData> GetData(string address);
}
```

If this is not possible because the different systems require a different set of parameters, you can use the first interface and instead pass the parameters to the constructors of the different implementations. Since the constructors are never part of the interface, you can always do that.

Yet another possibility is to add an extra generic type parameter for an address object.

```
public interface IDataSource<TData, TAddress>
{
    IEnumerable<TData> GetData(TAddress address);
}
```

---

If the different data sources need to be compatible, e.g. because you want to insert them into a `List<T>`, you can declare a non-generic interface as well

```
public interface IDataSource
{
    IEnumerable GetData();
}

public interface IDataSource<TData> : IDataSource
{
    IEnumerable<TData> GetData();
}
```

An implementation would implement the non-generic interface explicitly and thus automatically hide its members, if not accessed through `IDataSource`. The list can now be declared as `List<IDataSource>`.